# Django modelForm update certain fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a '*Farm*' model and a corresponding ModelForm as follows:

```
class FarmForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Farm
        fields = ['farm_name','address','farm_size', 'latitude', 'longitude']
```

I can save a new *Farm* object through my client app (it requires that I fill in all the fields mentioned in my ModelForm).

I want to have another view where in I can update an existing *Farm* where the user can perhaps insert/update only those fields he/she wants to change. I tried something like following by passing only one of the field values through Postman but it gives me Form_not_valid error:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def updateFarm(request, farmId):
   farm = Farm.objects.get(id=farmId)
   form = FarmForm(instance=farm, data=request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
       farm = form.save()
       farm = Farm.objects.filter(id=farm.id)
       serializer = FarmSerializer(farm, many=True)
       return JSONResponse(serializer.data) 
       #return Response("Data saved")
   else:
       return Response("Form not valid, insert correct fields.")
```

How can I build my view that let's user update only those fields he thinks are relevant? My url: `url(r'^farms/update/(?P<farmId>\d\d)/$', views.updateFarm),`

Comment: You want to call form is_valid, but how will your form know which fields the user wants to change and validate those only?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a boolean hidden form field for every field in your model, that gets set when a field is modified. For example `name` input:

```
<input id="id_name" maxlength="100" name="name" type="text">
```

will be followed by a `name__specified` hidden input:

```
<input id="id_name__specified" name="name__specified" type="hidden">
```

You track changes to field `name` with some js (very easy with plain js or jquery) and update `name__specified` accordingly to true/false.

In order to do this automatically and be able to re-use it, you can abstract this in a base form class and keep your form simple:

```
class BaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    suffix = '__specified'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BaseForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        fields = list(self.fields)
        for f in fields:
            # Set the field default value from the instance
            self.fields[f].widget.attrs['default'] = getattr(self.instance, f)

            # JS tracking field changes
            js = """
            document.getElementById("id_%s").value =
            this.value != this.getAttribute("default");
            """ % (f + self.suffix)
            self.fields[f].widget.attrs['onchange'] = js

            self.fields[f + self.suffix] = forms.BooleanField(
                widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
                required=False
            )

    def clean(self):
        data = super(BaseForm, self).clean()

        flags = [f for f in self.fields if self.suffix in f]
        for x in flags:
            specified = data.get(x, False)

            if not specified:
                field = x[:-len(self.suffix)]

                # If not specified grab it's current value from the instance
                data[field] = getattr(self.instance, field)

                # If the form validation complains that it's missing
                # clear the error since we are not changing it's value
                if field in self.errors:
                    del self.errors[field]

        return data
```

So your modified form:

```
class FarmForm(BaseForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Farm
        fields = ['farm_name','address','farm_size', 'latitude', 'longitude']
```

Note, you should pass the instance when instantiating a form in your GET function or simply inherit your view from `UpdateView` so that will be handled automatically:

```
class MyView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    form_class = FarmForm
    queryset = Farm.objects.all()
```

Now you can do partial updates!